# How to extract axios response data into variables?

Tags: laravel, vue.js

In routes, I define a route "/ajax/tutorials/unique/images" that returns the below output:

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "path": "/images/posts/1474360249_qDhAVF0mA4TnCVUmfcIpkNtvEkyhpV.png"
        },
        {
            "path": "/images/posts/1475575942_ZjuBj3u1rIvxdz1sK0pAuufzY8yjCT.png"
        },
        {
            "path": "/images/posts/1476871481_H63O2o55sBg8Qx1bf6S8wW1M82XXJ1.png"
        },
        {
            "path": "/images/posts/1476896115_JdyLpsxpcfL8kcpUwpFURV963WdeNa.png"
        },
        {
            "path": "/images/posts/1487368925_RSouQqnDiu1ieBGfWStfHlodcptVWA.png"
        },
        {
            "path": "/images/posts/1487368919_iAJUQpd3qx7RTB3ZnMsND0KmjrKrKu.png"
        }
    ],
    "paginator": {
        "total_count": 15,
        "total_pages": 3,
        "current_page": 1,
        "limit": 6
    }
}
```

I wrote this code in app.js file:

```
new Vue({
    el: '#app',

    data: {
        images: [],
        pagination: [],
    },

    mounted() {
        axios.get('/ajax/tutorials/unique/images')
            .then(function (response) {
                this.images = response.data.data;
                this.pagination = response.data.paginator;

                console.log(response.data.data);
                console.log(response.data.paginator);
            });
    }
});
```

The images and pagination array that I define in app.js don't have any value after running this code, but in the browser console I can see the output:
[image: The response in browser console]
But Vue doesn't set the response to variables:

[image: The output by VueDevTools]

When I use arrow function for callback it works, the problem is that I want to set two variable.

```
new Vue({
    el: '#app',

    data: {
        images: [],
        pagination: [],
    },

    mounted() {
        axios.get('/ajax/tutorials/unique/images')
            .then(response => this.images = response.data.data);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Oh I didn't know that, We can use array in arrow function for callback, So I changed code like below, and it's work

```
axios.get('/ajax/tutorials/unique/images')
    .then( response => [
        this.images = response.data.data,
        this.pagination = response.data.paginator,
    ]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to return a function from data.

```
data: function(){
  return {
    images: [],
    pagination: [],
 }
}
```

This is how Vue will observe the `images` and `pagination` changes later when you component runs.

Comment: Returning a function for `data` will only work with Vue components. The OP is clearly using a regular `Vue` instance.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply do this:

```
    axios.get('/ajax/tutorials/unique/images')
        .then(response => {
            this.images = response.data.data
            this.pagination = response.data.paginator

            console.log(response.data.data)
            console.log(response.data.paginator)
        })
```